# Entity framework is not supported in ASP.net core -Visual studio 2015

Tags: database, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am working with asp.net core- Visual studio 2015.While accessing my sql database the following error occurs. "Please add the Entity.framework.SqlServerCompact NuGet package to the project". Please let me know how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well with ASP.net Core everything is optional and as Nuget packages which means you have to bring them in your project if you want to use them.

If you want to add any Nuget package to your project you just need to open your project json file and add this line into dependencies:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Or run npm install in your project directory:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Then locate your tools section in your project json and add this into it:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final"
```

If you had any problem with the version see if using this version is helping:

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

Reason is this is a known issue you can find here:

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3742

Check the version in case has changed. For a more detailed instructions look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db

Comment: Hi Yaser, I have tried as you have said. But I am getting the following exception. "Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet (>= 1.0.0-preview3-final)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'." Please let me know is ther any solution ton resolve it.